# Pattern to group many internet calls in a single one passing an array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, tableview

I have a tableview (Xcode and Swift 5) with each item representing a calculation with some assets implemented by a complex object structure. I need to refresh each calculus (item) every five seconds with prices I gather from the internet. I'm looking for a way or pattern to group the internet calls for each item in a single one RFC call passing an array to the RFC and receiving back N assets price in a single JSON array, instead of N internet calls and N answers of the RFC that are heavier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still on the process, but the way I'm going through is to create a Singleton to keep the prices per asset (SingletonAssetsAndPrices), a Singleton to gather the data from the internet (NetworkManager) and notify SingletonAssetsAndPrices that data are being pulled in every 5 seconds.

Since the calculation is being done by a complex object structure that have internally references to "Asset and Price" objects in memory, the object being updated in SingletonAssesAndPrices reflects on the calculation.